# How can I continue the process and print out their process ids?

Tags: c++

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
 int pid;
 printf ("\nI'm the original process with PID %d.\n", getpid ());
 pid = fork ();                     /* Duplicate process. Child and parent continue from here */
 if (pid != 0)                      /* pid is non-zero, so I must be the parent */
   {
     printf ("I'm the parent process with PID %d.\n", getpid());
     printf ("My child's PID is %d.\n", pid);
   }
 else                              /* pid is zero, so I must be the child */
   {
     printf ("I'm the child process with PID %d.\n", getpid ());
     pid= fork();      
     printf ("I'm the child's child with PID %d.\n", getpid ());    
   }
 printf ("PID %d terminates.\n", getpid());
}
```

So far my program is working, but I need my program to continue with 9 more processes indicating process 2 is the parent of process 3 and process 3 is the parent of process 4, and so on. So far I've been able to output the parent with process id, along with the child process id. The issue is, it only outputs the parent and child once. I require that my program create a chain of 10 processes and prints out their parent and child process id's. Currently I've been able to output parent id and its child id only once.
What would be the best method to accomplish this?

Comment: You use the `c++` tag and your using `using namespace std;` in your code but this looks a lot like `C` other than those two things. Are you sure this isnt C?

Comment: Presumably, after the second call of `fork()`, which will be executed by the first child process, you need more calls of `fork()` to launch grandchildren of the first process.

Comment: So I just add nine more fork()?

Comment: I didn't say that.  You need to think a bit harder about what you are trying to achieve, and what it means.   Will nine calls of `fork()` give you what you want?  Will it give you other things you don't want?

Comment: Adding nine fork() calls gives me other things I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static int counter = 1;    

void init_proc()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        if(counter==10)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
            init_proc();
        }
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
        printf("Process %d with child %d\n", getpid(), pid);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: Could not initialize process\n");
    }
}    

int main ()
{
     init_proc();
     return 0;
}
```

Notice that `pid != 0` doesn't necessarily mean that you are in the parrent process. If `fork()` returns -1 it means there was an error. More info about this here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork .

In my example i didn't use the printf's you wanted but you can play with it a little to get the results you want.

Comment: That's it!! The output is correct, its exactly what I wanted. Your code is completely different from my code. I'm going to incorporate your code and try to make it work with my code. Thank you M. Kostas.

Comment: No problem. If you find any difficulties or you don't understand how something works don't hesitate to ask. The most important part is understanding what you are doing. Good luck finishing it!

Comment: I have a question regarding your code. What kind of function is void init_proc()? I know that init is the parent of all processes on a system. 
I don't understand line 24 through 27?

Comment: init_proc() is the function that i defined in line 8. I'm doing a recursive call of it (that means im calling the function inside the function). That's how the processes are created. In lines 24 - 27 i'm telling to every parrent process that it should wait the process with the specified pid. The status var is not doing anything in the code, it is just needed for the waitpid function to work. Also the WNOHANG means that the parent should not care if the child terminates or not. Read here for more information: http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid

Comment: If the name of the function confuses you, you can name it anything you want, like void myfunction() or something, but be sure to change it in the code in line 21 too